# Include a dynamic page using dsp include in atg

Tags: java, jsp, atg, oracle-commerce, atg-droplet

I'm trying to include a page `listusers.jsp` which simply says "Hello World". I'm reading the name of the listusers.jsp from a parameter as shown below from profile.jsp.

```
<!-- profile.jsp -->
<table width="100%" border="0px">
    <tr><td>
    <table border="0px">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <dsp:a page="profile.jsp">List Users
                <dsp:param name="includepage"  value="listusers.jsp"/>  
            </dsp:a>
            <dsp:a page="profile.jsp">Shop
                <dsp:param name="includepage"  value="shop.jsp"/>   
            </dsp:a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <dsp:getvalueof param="includepage" id="subpage" >
            <dsp:include page="<%= subpage %>" />
        </dsp:getvalueof>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

This is giving me the following error when I'm trying to open `profile.jsp`

```
A:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\atgbases\ATG\work\Catalina\localhost\MyStore\org\apache\jsp\profile_jsp.java:168: error: method setPage in class IncludeTag cannot be applied to given types;
            _jspx_th_dsp_005finclude_005f1.setPage( subpage );
                                          ^
  required: String
  found: Object
  reason: actual argument Object cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion
1 error
1 warning
```

Please let me know the right way of including a dynamic page using

Answer (score 2):

You are simply giving the `getvalueof` the wrong attribute for the variable.

Instead of:

```
<dsp:getvalueof param="includepage" id="subpage" >
    <dsp:include page="<%= subpage %>" />
</dsp:getvalueof>
```

Rather try:

```
<dsp:getvalueof param="includepage" var="subpage" >
    <dsp:include page="<%= subpage %>" />
</dsp:getvalueof>
```

Note the attribute is `var` not `id`.

Comment: Thanks, will try and come back. Don't completely understand what you mean by passing a parameter to the page, but I have passed the subpage as parameter `<dsp:param name="includepage"  value="shop.jsp"/>` Isn't this same thing as passing the parameter?

Comment: I've reread your code. It probably will work. I missed the `<dsp:param>` inside the `<dsp:a>` tag. Will remove the note from my answer.

Comment: As above but `<dsp:include page="${ subpage }" />` would remove the script lets and use EL variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think specifying `idtype="java.lang.String"` to the `<dsp:getvalueof />` tag might resolve your problem. It looks like currently the variable, `subpage` is created as `Object` rather than `String`.

```
<dsp:getvalueof param="includepage" id="subpage" idtype="java.lang.String">
    <dsp:include page="<%= subpage %>" />
</dsp:getvalueof>
```